# How to showing data on blade with pass through 2 table FK

Tags: laravel

I have 3 table like **users** , **data_users** , **practice**

```
users      : id , name ,dob ,email , etc . . .

data_users : id , user_id , number_exp , etc . .

practice   : id , data_user_id , practice_number , etc ....
```

in 3 tables connect by relation belongsTo and  and want to showing this .
i want to show data on table practice :

My controller :

```
public function show()
{
    $practice= Practice::with('data_users')->get();

    return view('admin.practice' ,['practice'=>$practice]);
}
```

my view

```
 <table class="table table-bordered">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>No</th>
                  <th>Name</th>
                  <th>No Surat</th>
                  <th>Date</th>
                  <th>Status</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                @foreach ($practice as $i)
                <tr>
                  <th scope="row">1</th>
                  <td>{{ $i->data_users->users->name}}</td>//i want to show name but i cant show this
                  <td>{{ $i->practice_number}}</td>
                  <td>{{ $i->practice_date}}</td>
                  <td>{{ $i->status}}</td>
                </tr>
                @endforeach
              </tbody>
            </table>
```

i have problem to showing Data '**NAME**' form table **users** , and i just can showing **id**  from **data_users**

but still error Trying to Get property

Comment: do you have relationship between users and data_users?

Comment: yes i have , data_users belongsTo users

Comment: try my answer please, you should pin also users to the view, that was the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
public function show()
{
    $practice= Practice::with('data_users', 'data_users.users')->get();

    return view('admin.practice' ,['practice'=>$practice]);
}
```

Comment: oke i try . how about my view ? {{ $i->data_users->users->name}} is right ?

Comment: should be fine :)

Comment: Call to undefined relationship [users] on model [App\User].

Comment: i have relation on model Data_user . its belongsTo to users

Comment: could you please paste it ?

Comment: you can also make relationship that users hasOne user_data

Comment: and do you have relationship between users and practice maybe?

Comment: oh i solved it . i need at relation on model Practice to data_user . thanks full

Answer (score 0):

You are returning `$practice` collection from controller, trying to foreach `$riwayat` collection.

Comment: iam sorry iam typo for my copy paste ,now iam update my thread